# Send UIImageView (label background) to back to display UILabel

Tags: uiimageview, uilabel

I am trying to add an image as a background to a UILabel, but my UILabel's title cannot be seen, even though I tried to send the background image to the back. My code is below and any advice on how to help with this would be great, thanks!

```
UIImageView *labelBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[myLabel addSubview:labelBackground];
[myLabel sendSubviewToBack:labelBackground];
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myLabel setText:title];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a view (your image view) as a subview to another view (your label), the subview will always be in front of its superview. They would either need to be siblings:

```
[myContainer addSubview:labelBackground];
[myContainer addSubview:myLabel];
```

or better yet, the label should be a subview of the image view:

```
[labelBackground addSubview:myLabel];
[myContainer addSubView:labelBackground];
```

Another solution might be to use your image as a background color for your label:

```
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myUIImage]];
```

But note that the image will be repeated instead of centered or stretched.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the UILabel as a subview of the UIImageView, rather than the other way around.

This will result in the UIImageView being the "container" of the label, and thus the label being on top of the UIImageView.